# DJANGO-increment global variable in function by every get. Request

Tags: python, django

the first code is the file that named `tes.py` and in this file is a function that named `Program`.

for every `url.request`(second code) it proceses  many things and will save to my db table.

**at this first code I defined  `id` as a "increment count" global varible .**

golbal variable code:

> ```
> id = request.session.get('id')
> if not id:
>     id = 1
> request.session['id'] = id
> ```

I want for every `get.Request` in `urls.py`, the value of id will update by this relation:

> id= id+1

But its value does not change.

And I dont know why even though I defined `id` as Global variable !

HELP PLEASE.

```js
import  sqlite3
from .models import OrdersStudent ,OrdersStudent1 ,EditStudentDatasheet ,OrdersDouble , Nodecode
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_globals import globals

global j





def Program(request):

    id = request.session.get('id')
    if not id:
        id = 1
    request.session['id'] = id




    R = 6378.0
    zz = 0

    conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")

    j = 0




    sql = 'DELETE FROM orders_Double'
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()



    EditStudentDatasheet.objects.filter(UserId=41907).delete()
    EditStudentDatasheet.objects.filter(UserId=41787).delete()
    Nodecode.objects.filter(studentidof=41907).delete()
    Nodecode.objects.filter(studentidof=41787).delete()
    NodecodeNumberOfSubscriptions = list(Nodecode.objects.all())
    Datasheet = list(EditStudentDatasheet.objects.all())
    orders_student = {}

    orders_student={}.copy()
    x = Datasheet[0].Lat
    Dictionary1  = {}
    MinOfPair = 50
    capacity = 3



    while (MinOfPair <= 500):
        ThisCheck = True
        DoubleMergePairLAST={}
        DoubleMergePair = {}
        DoublePair={}
        DoubleMergePair = {}

        ObjectDatasheet = Datasheet[0]
        ObjectDatasheet1 = Datasheet[0]
        ObjectDatasheet2 = Datasheet[0]




        iii = 0
        iii1 = 0
        iii2 =0
        jz = 1
        for i1 in range(len(Datasheet) ):

            checking = False



            for i2 in range(i1+1 , len(Datasheet) ):
                lat1 = radians(Datasheet[i1].Lat)
                lon1 = radians(Datasheet[i1].Long)
                lat2 = radians(Datasheet[i2].Lat)
                lon2 = radians(Datasheet[i2].Long)

                dlon = lon2 - lon1
                dlat = lat2 - lat1

                a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
                c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

                distance = R * c *1000

                if (distance < MinOfPair):
                    ObjectDatasheet1 = Datasheet[i1]
                    ObjectDatasheet2 = Datasheet[i2]
                    DoublePair.setdefault(Datasheet[i1].UserId, []).append(ObjectDatasheet2.UserId)
                    iii1 = i1
                    iii2 = i2

            if (checking == False):
                DoublePair.setdefault(Datasheet[i1].UserId, []).append(Datasheet[i1].UserId)

            if (len(DoublePair[Datasheet[i1].UserId]) != 0):

                companies = (jz, Datasheet[i1].UserId , Datasheet[i1].Lat ,Datasheet[i1].Long , zz)

                sql = '''INSERT INTO orders_double(groupid, userid , lat ,long ,id) VALUES (?, ? , ? ,? , ?)'''
                c = conn.cursor()
                c.execute(sql, companies)
                zz=zz+1



                for i3 in range(0,len(DoublePair[Datasheet[i1].UserId])):

                    for i4 in range(len(Datasheet)):

                        if(Datasheet[i4].UserId == DoublePair[Datasheet[i1].UserId][i3]):
                            companies = (jz, DoublePair[Datasheet[i1].UserId][i3], Datasheet[i4].Lat, Datasheet[i4].Long , zz)



                            c.execute(sql, companies)
                            zz = zz + 1



                            break

                jz=jz+1

        conn.commit()
        orderDoubles1 = list(OrdersDouble.objects.all())
        m = len(orderDoubles1)

        for i1 in range(orderDoubles1[len(orderDoubles1)-1].groupid):

                DoubleMergePair.setdefault(i1, [])
                orderDoubles11 = list(OrdersDouble.objects.filter(groupid=(i1+1)))

                for i2 in range(len(orderDoubles11) ):


                    booli = True
                    for i5 in range(len(DoubleMergePair[i1])):

                        if (DoubleMergePair[i1][i5].userid == orderDoubles11[i2].userid):

                           booli = False
                           break

                    if (booli == True):
                        DoubleMergePair.setdefault(i1, []).append(orderDoubles11[i2])

                    for i3 in range(len(orderDoubles1)):

                        if (orderDoubles11[i2].userid == orderDoubles1[i3].userid):
                            orderDoubles2 = list(OrdersDouble.objects.filter(groupid=(orderDoubles1[i3].groupid)))
                            for i4 in range(len(orderDoubles2)):
                                booli=True
                                for i5 in range(len(DoubleMergePair[i1])):
                                    if (DoubleMergePair[i1][i5].userid == orderDoubles2[i4].userid):
                                        booli=False
                                        break

                                if (booli == True):
                                    DoubleMergePair.setdefault(i1, []).append(orderDoubles2[i4])


        for i1 in range(len(DoubleMergePair)):
            for i4 in range(len(DoubleMergePair[i1])):
                for i2 in range(i1 + 1,len(DoubleMergePair)):
                    for i3 in range( len(DoubleMergePair[i2])):
                        if (DoubleMergePair[i1][i4].userid == DoubleMergePair[i2][i3].userid):

                            for i5 in range(len(DoubleMergePair[i1])):
                                mybool = False
                                for i6 in range(len(DoubleMergePair[i2])):
                                    if (DoubleMergePair[i1][i5].userid == DoubleMergePair[i2][i6].userid):
                                        mybool = True

                                if (mybool == False):
                                    DoubleMergePair.setdefault(i2, []).append(DoubleMergePair[i1][i5])
                                kkk=0

        for key1, list1 in DoubleMergePair.items():

            mmm = 0
            for key2, list2 in DoubleMergePair.items():

                commons = []

                for i1 in range(len(list1)):
                    for i2 in range(len(list2)):
                        if (list1[i1].userid == list2[i2].userid):
                            commons.append(list1[i1].userid)
                            mmm = 0

                if (len(commons) > 0 and key1 != key2):

                    if (len(list1) > len(list2)):
                        DoubleMergePair[key2].clear()
                    else:
                        DoubleMergePair[key1].clear()

        i1i = 1
        for key1, list1 in DoubleMergePair.items():
            if (len(list1) > 0):
                for item in list1:
                    DoubleMergePairLAST.setdefault(i1i, []).append(item)

                i1i = i1i + 1

        max = 0
        for key, listMerge in DoubleMergePairLAST.items():

            if (len(listMerge) > max):
                max = len(listMerge)



        for key , listMerge in DoubleMergePairLAST.items():

            if (len(listMerge) == capacity):
                j=j+1
                for item in listMerge:
                    orders_student.setdefault(j, []).append(item)
                DoubleMergePair[key].clear()
                for i in range(capacity):
                    for itemDatasheet in Datasheet:
                        if(itemDatasheet.userid == listMerge[i].userid):
                            Datasheet.remove(itemDatasheet)

                    for itemNodecodeNumberOfSubscriptions in NodecodeNumberOfSubscriptions:
                        if (itemNodecodeNumberOfSubscriptions.studentidof == listMerge[i].studentidof):
                            NodecodeNumberOfSubscriptions.remove(itemNodecodeNumberOfSubscriptions)

            if (len(listMerge) > capacity):
                orderOFss= []
                orderOFsss=[]
                maxnumitem1=[]

                for i in range(len(listMerge)):
                    orderOFss = list(Nodecode.objects.filter(studentidof=(listMerge[i].userid)))
                    orderOFsss.append(orderOFss[0])





                while (ThisCheck == True):
                    for item in orderOFsss:
                        item.nodes =item.nodes= item.nodes =item.nodes[:-1]

                    p = 0



                    for item1 in orderOFsss:
                        orderOFsssReserve=[]
                        p = 0
                        for item2 in orderOFsss:
                            if (item1.nodes == item2.nodes and p <= capacity - 1):
                                orderOFsssReserve.append(item2)
                                p=p+1

                    if (p >= capacity):
                        ThisCheck = False
                        j = j+1

                        for item in orderOFsssReserve:
                            fforderOFsssReservefff=[]
                            for item0 in orderDoubles1:
                                if(item.studentidof== item0.userid):

                                    orders_student.setdefault(j, []).append(item0)
                                    break




        if (ThisCheck == False):
            companies = (
            id, capacity,1, 1 ,j)

            sql = '''INSERT INTO new_orders_groups(groupid, capacity , obj1 , author , id) VALUES ( ? , ? ,? , ? , ? )'''
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute(sql, companies)



            for i in range(capacity):
                companies = (id, orders_student[j][i].userid, orders_student[j][i].lat, orders_student[j][i].long, id , capacity , j ,1)

                sql = '''INSERT INTO new_orders_student(groupid, userid , lat ,long ,id , capacity , obj1_id , author) VALUES ( ? , ? ,? , ? , ?, ? , ? , ?  )'''
                c = conn.cursor()
                c.execute(sql, companies)
                id=id+1

            conn.commit()

            break


        MinOfPair = MinOfPair + 50


    m=0

    id = id + 1
    return HttpResponse()
```

```html
from .views import PostList , studentDetail ,StudentsDatasheetGetView ,EditOrderStudents ,  EditStudentsDatasheetGetView
from django.urls import path , include

from .tes import Program

urlpatterns = [

   path('newgp/', Program, name='Program' ),]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: I edited  the caption...

Comment: Using globals is usually a pretty bad idea, even more when you have an entire ORM to easily access a database. Why don't you just create a model to store the requests?

Comment: please exlpane more